# Electrostatic energy of two point charges separated by a given distance

Tags: energy, electrostatics, electric-fields

Find an expression for the electrostatic energy between two point charges of charge $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ separated by a variable distance $z$ using the formula:

$W = \int_{V'}{\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 E^2 d\tau'}$

Separate this expression into a divergent part that doesn't depend on $z$, and a finite part that does depend on $z$.

My attempt:
I set $Q_1$ on the origin, and $Q_2$ a distance z away on the z-axis. The vector connecting $Q_1$ to $Q_2$ is given by:

$r = (0,0,z)$

The vector connecting $Q_1$ to the reference point is:

$r_1 = (x',y',z')$

The vector that connects $Q_2$ to the reference point is:

$r - r_1 = (x',y',z'-z)$

$E = \frac{kQ_1r_1}{|r_1|^3} +\frac{kQ_2(r-r_1)}{|r-r_1|^3}$

$|r_1|^3 = (x'^2 + y'^2 + z'^2)^{3/2}$

$|r-r_1|^3 = (x'^2 + y'^2 + (z'-z)^2)^{3/2}$

The volume integral is then evaluated over all of real space, but I'm really not sure how to evaluate it, if there's a simpler way, or if my line of reasoning is correct to begin with.

Edit: Following the suggestion in the comments to make the origin my reference point:

$r_1 = (0,0,0)$

$r_2 = (0,0,z)$

then,

$E = \frac{kQ_1}{|r_1|^3}r_1 + \frac{kQ_2}{|r_2|^3}r_2$

Where

$|r_1|^3 = 0$

$|r_2|^3 = z^3$

However, this causes the term involving $Q_1$ to be infinite, so I'm not sure how exactly to proceed.

Comment: Why don't you take the location of Q1 as your reference point? This will simplify your math. Since what is required is the Energy (between) the two charges, the choice of your reference point is totally up to you.

Comment: I tried this, but immediately ended up with an infinite term for $Q_1$ (see my edits)

Comment: I'd check the expressions for your field in your edit. Anyway, of course you'll get two diverging contributions - this is classical EM, see http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_28.html

Comment: The modified E has two parts: first part will be divergent and independent of z, while the second part is finite and depends on z. I thought that is exactly what the question is asking for.

Comment: Well, the electric field has a divergent term independent of z and a finite term, however when calculating the electrostatic energy over an infinite volume, I found that it all becomes divergent.